# not receiving parse push in android, it causes app has stopped popup

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have looked more than 2 hours for a solution, but no chance.

I have installed parse into my application android and I have installed it in my phone (android s4 mini, using wifi currently).

Here is how my parse is setup in my project:

```
Parse.initialize(mInstance, App.parseAppId, App.parseAppKey);
// Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(mInstance, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I see that parse logged my installation
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0865kofmd9

But when I send a push, my app crash "Unfortunately Application has stopped working"

Here is my androidmanifest:
http://pastebin.com/UySbvP8P

Any advise please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your androidmanifest.xml ?

Comment: Hi Andre, here is my androidmanfiest http://pastebin.com/UySbvP8P

Answer (score 1):

Please try to replace the default parse push receiver with this: :

remove:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(mInstance, MainActivity.class);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="ParsePushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE"/>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

ParsePushReceiver.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

public class ParsePushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent newIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        newIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        context.startActivity(newIntent);
    }
}
```

App.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, parseAppId, parseAppKey);
    if (ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation() != null && ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getCreatedAt() == null) {
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    //track error
                }
            }
        });
    }
    mInstance = this;
    if (isOnline()) {
        makeJsonObjectRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre for helping, I did modifications, but still issue, when I send a push, my app crash "Unfortunately Application has stopped working"

Comment: Have u first uninstalled the application so a new parse installation will be created ? Is the devicetoken set ? There must be some info in your log also.

Comment: yes I have uninstalled, I see devicetoken in parse. regarding my log, how I can see it in my phone or where exaclty? Thanks

Comment: Here is logcat : http://pastebin.com/Ka16pxE4 Just for info, parse application_id and client_key, I'm downloading them from a json file hosted in my server, so when app launch, i download first json and I extract these variables. This is the issue? if yes how it's possible to do that?

Comment: Andre, here is how my class App.java looks like http://pastebin.com/Cuv3Vpu1 I think the issue is in iniating app, when it's in background, something like that. what you think?

Comment: Updated answer, can u please try to initialize parse this way ?  (Saving the installation this way is just a recommendation). In case your isOnline() returns false, your application singelton will always be null.

Comment: I've never initialized parse NOT in the application onCreate().

Comment: Andre, you did Parse.initialize(this, parseAppId, parseAppKey); but parseAppId and parseAppKey values are initialized only after makeJsonObjectRequest() when I call json from my server, so how it will work?

Comment: Works everything if you initialize parse this way ? As i saied i've never lazy initialized parse. I'm not sure if it will work this way.

Comment: yes I really need this solution, to call json to get parse client id and key. as I manage many applications, and they are sharing all some json file from server. so with json file, I can change values of apps easily :( :(